# Where seems ignored in mysql cursor

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursor, mariadb

I'm trying to use a cursor to process rows which are containing a string:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE REVERT_ALL(IN TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(255))
  BEGIN
    DECLARE bDone INT;
    DECLARE CH_ID INT;
    DECLARE CH_CHANGE CHAR;

    DECLARE curs cursor for 
      SELECT `table_id`, `change_type` FROM mysql_snapshot.db_changes where `table_name` = "rooms";
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET bDone = 1;

    OPEN curs;

    insert into splog set text = concat('SELECT id, `table_name`, table_id, `change_type` FROM mysql_snapshot.db_changes where table_name = ',TABLE_NAME, ';');

    SET bDone = 0;
    REPEAT
      FETCH curs INTO CH_ID, CH_CHANGE;

      insert into splog set text = concat_ws( ' -- ', 'CH_ID ', CH_ID,' TABLE ',TABLE_NAME, ' CH_CHANGE ', CH_CHANGE);

      UNTIL bDone END REPEAT;

      CLOSE curs;
    END;
```

For a reason which I'm searching most of the day, the

```
where `table_name` = "rooms"
```

seems to be ignored. The plan is to change it to

```
where `table_name` = TABLE_NAME
```

to use the procedure argument. I just get all rows. The inserts are there for logging and debugging.

Comment: Can you clarify, `\`table_name\` = "rooms"` is ignored, or `\`table_name\` = TABLE_NAME` is ignored?

Comment: Sure, my expectation is to get only result rows where the table_name column contains the string "rooms" respectively the string which is in the argument TABLE_NAME. But the trigger contains all rows of the table not depending on the contents of the column table_name.

Answer (score 1):

You have ambiguity between the procedure parameter name `TABLE_NAME` and the table column name `table_name`. It should be avoided, because it causes obscure problems just like this one.

In this case, inside the procedure, `TABLE_NAME`, `table_name`, and `table_name` in backticks are all [interpreted as the local variable name](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/local-variable-scope.html) (parameter name). So, your condition `'where table_name = ',TABLE_NAME` is always true; and when you replace `TABLE_NAME` with the `"rooms"` literal, the condition is always true if you call the procedure with `"rooms"` as an argument, and is always false otherwise. Consider this simplified example:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS pr;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t;
CREATE PROCEDURE pr (IN TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(255)) 
  SELECT `id`, `table_name`, TABLE_NAME FROM t
;

CREATE TABLE t (id INT, `table_name` VARCHAR(255));
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1,'hotels'),(2,'rooms');

CALL pr("rooms");
CALL pr("foo");
```

You will get

```
MariaDB [test]> CALL pr("rooms");
+------+--------------+------------+
| id   | `table_name` | TABLE_NAME |
+------+--------------+------------+
|    1 | rooms        | rooms      |
|    2 | rooms        | rooms      |
+------+--------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> CALL pr("foo");
+------+--------------+------------+
| id   | `table_name` | TABLE_NAME |
+------+--------------+------------+
|    1 | foo          | foo        |
|    2 | foo          | foo        |
+------+--------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

As you see, regardless the argument, `table_name` is always equal `TABLE_NAME`, for all rows.

Now, if you replace `TABLE_NAME` with explicit `"rooms"`:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS pr;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t;
CREATE PROCEDURE pr (IN TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(255)) 
  SELECT `id`, `table_name`, "rooms" FROM t
;

CREATE TABLE t (id INT, `table_name` VARCHAR(255));
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1,'hotels'),(2,'rooms');

CALL pr("rooms");
CALL pr("foo");
```

Now the condition `table_name = "rooms"` would be true for the first call, for all rows, and false for the second call, for all rows:

```
MariaDB [test]> CALL pr("rooms");
+------+--------------+-------+
| id   | `table_name` | rooms |
+------+--------------+-------+
|    1 | rooms        | rooms |
|    2 | rooms        | rooms |
+------+--------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> CALL pr("foo");
+------+--------------+-------+
| id   | `table_name` | rooms |
+------+--------------+-------+
|    1 | foo          | rooms |
|    2 | foo          | rooms |
+------+--------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

What you need instead is a different name for the parameter:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS pr;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t;
CREATE PROCEDURE pr (IN T_NAME VARCHAR(255)) 
  SELECT `id`, `table_name`, T_NAME FROM t
;

CREATE TABLE t (id INT, `table_name` VARCHAR(255));
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1,'hotels'),(2,'rooms');

CALL pr("rooms");
CALL pr("foo");
```

Now the comparison `table_name = T_NAME` would actually make sense;

```
MariaDB [test]> CALL pr("rooms");
+------+------------+--------+
| id   | table_name | T_NAME |
+------+------------+--------+
|    1 | hotels     | rooms  |
|    2 | rooms      | rooms  |
+------+------------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> CALL pr("foo");
+------+------------+--------+
| id   | table_name | T_NAME |
+------+------------+--------+
|    1 | hotels     | foo    |
|    2 | rooms      | foo    |
+------+------------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```